# Concatenation with arrays in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void mystrcat(char destination[], const char source[]){
    int counter = 0;
    while(source[counter] != '/0'){
        destination += source[counter];
        counter++;
    }
    destination += '/0';
}

int main(){

}
```

For my code, when I try to concatenate with the function mystrcat, my school's test bed says that there was a segmentation error.  The purpose of my function is to concatenate while removing the NULL from the end of destination and adding it to the end of source.  Is there a segmentation error because I am not removing NULL?  If so, how do I access the last element of the array?  The number of elements is unknown so I don't know if I can use pop_back.  Thank you.

Edit:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void mystrcat(char destination[], const char source[]){
    int counter = 0;
    int counter2 = 0;

    while(destination[counter2] != '/0'){
        counter2++;
    }

    while(source[counter] != '/0'){
        destination[counter2 - 1] = source[counter];
        counter++;
    }
    destination[counter] = '/0';
}

int main(){

}
```

is my edited code but now the testbed says that it is taking too long and crashes.

Comment: What do you expect `destination += source[counter];` to do?

Comment: Go through source and add each char to the array destination.

Comment: I suspect *going through source* is why you have the loop, though. That statement alone adds the integral value of whatever `source[counter]` is to the pointer `destination`, quite possibly moving it out of your string immediately.

Comment: @EdHeal, Or `std::string`s (I do that, too).

Comment: @chris, Sorry about that, I thought the array arguments were copied...

Comment: @APerson, The array decays into a pointer, which is then copied. The signature is a disguise for `void mystrcat(const char *, const char *)`. Speaking of which, @OP, you can't use `const` if it needs to be modified (by adding the other string onto it).

Comment: I can't use cstrings for this assignment.  And the assignment had that function line in it.  :(

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in C++ have an interesting property where they can easily decay to pointers.

`destination += source[counter];` does not append `source[counter]` to the end of destination.
Instead, `destination` has decayed to a pointer and this operation is doing pointer arithmatic on `destination`.

Instead, you want to do `destination[destinationLocation] = source[counter];` to actually set the character in `destination`.

Don't forget to set `destination[end] = '\0';` at the end to null terminate the `destination` array.

One final thing to watch out for is that C++ will not make sure that your arrays are properly sized. If `destination` is not of the proper size, the code will fail at run time with a segmentation fault.

---

For future reference, you might want to look into using C++'s [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) class. std::vector is a variable sized array-like container which automatically keeps track of its size and memory usage. Using pure arrays in C++ is sometimes difficult and error prone (as you have just seen), so std::vector can make things easier.

Comment: To make it clear, both `source` and `destination` are pointers right from the get-go due to the function signature.

Comment: How would I set the last element in destination to the first element of source?  The size of both arrays is unknown for me.  Is there a function that I can use that will let me access the very last element?

Comment: @user3024476, chris's (now deleted comment) comment was correct. You just need to iterate over destination until you find the null.

Comment: Sorry, I noticed the question is actually halfway there, really, and then got lost on my comment. @user3024476, You currently loop through to find the end of `source`. What you need to do in order to concatenate another string is then go from that point on, copying from `destination` to `source`, and finally adding a null character. If the concatenated one is supposed to be in destination, switch the two in this comment and the code that finds the end of the string to be grown. With that signature, this function will have to trust that what's passed in is big enough to hold the final string.

Comment: I don't understand how I know what value the end of destination is when the number of elements of both arrays is unknown.  I know that I can't use a .size function to determine the size.

Answer (score 0):

Static arrays are a fixed sized in C++. That means you can't extend or shrink them at all under any circumstance.

There are three main alternatives to achieve what you're trying to do. From your code, it looks like the best one would be to use the `std::string` class (since you're using chars). It contains all the code to manage and concatenate the data very easily.

If you absolutely need an array, then `std::vector` would be the next best choice. It allows push and pop operations etc., and will automatically resize the underlying dynamic array as needed.

Finally, you could use a dynamic array directly. You would create and destroy it using `new []` and `delete []`. When you need to extend the array, you need to create a new one with the new size, copy the old data over, and destroy the old one. It's a lot of unnecessary extra work though, so the other two options are much better.

Comment: The guideline for the assignment says no strcat or any cstring functions.  :(

Comment: @user3024476, None of these fall into C string functions. They're preferred C++ alternatives, but if that's all your assignment says, they'll still end up just as badly when the spec is changed after the marker sees them used.

Comment: If the size of the arrays are unknown, how do I add them to a vector?  Would it be begin and end for the vector?

Comment: @user3024476: You can determine the size by counting characters until you reach the null terminator.